# Cannot figure out the error in simple PHP/MySQL "Q&A" DB

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating a simple questions DB, here are some details to start:

1st off, I am not using PDO - it's an old webapp, and this question is not about upgrading to PDO.

**The DB**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `questions` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `question` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `userID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '1',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;
```

**Already inside the DB:**

```
INSERT INTO `apl_questions` (`id`, `question`, `userID`, `active`) VALUES
(1, 'Do you have a dog?', 1, 1),
(2, 'Have you ever been arrested?', 1, 1),
(3, 'Pick yes or no...', 1, 1);
```

**The PHP**

```
$questionsResult = mysql_query("select * from questions where userID = 1 AND active = 1"); // Get all activated questions
    if(mysql_num_rows($questionsResult) > 0){
        $questions = mysql_fetch_assoc($questionsResult);
        var_dump($questions);
    }
```

**The RESULT (of the PHP)**

```
array(4) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["question"]=> string(18) "Do you have a dog?" ["userID"]=> string(1) "1" ["active"]=> string(1) "1" }
```

As you can see, this is only grabbing the first row - when it **should** be grabbing all rows since the userID and "active" column of all 3 rows are 1.  Anyone see anything here that could be causing this problem?  If I put the query into PHP MyAdmin, the query works correctly - so I have to assume at this point that it's the PHP...  This is blowing my mind!

Thanks.

Comment: Reading the [manual](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc) for the function you are having problems with is often a good idea.

Comment: @vascowhite I did read it.  Do you see my answer in there or something?

Comment: Yes I do:- "Returns an associative array that corresponds to the fetched _row_ and moves the internal data pointer ahead."

Comment: @vascowhite see below in "Sebas'" answer.

Comment: I think this question shouldn't be downvoted since it presents research an efforts, even though the subject *might* sound trivial at the first sight. See Alex's comments on my answer if you want to get a bit more advanced on the matter... ;)

Comment: @Sebas the manual is quite clear and following it would solve the problem, hence my -1 is remaining.

Comment: Everybody is free :-) I was just giving some support to something that I thought deserved at least a neutral position. I respect and don't judge your decision at all! This is healthy to know your opinion since this is a highly participative website ;) cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems mysql_fetch_assoc is *row* fetching, opposite to *bulk* fetching, which means it will fetch row per row inside a given array.

You have to loop over, for example in the php page:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   echo $row["userid"];
   echo $row["fullname"];
   echo $row["userstatus"];
}
```

rgds.

Comment: This isn't the normal operation of mysql_fetch_assoc... is it?)

Comment: I don't know, what do you mean normal? The sure thing is that it will return a given line, not a whole recordset

Comment: @Shackrock it is according to the manual "Returns an associative array that corresponds to the fetched row and moves the internal data pointer ahead."

Comment: @vascowhite I have it functionally returning an **array** of data in other parts of this webapp....

Comment: An array corresponding to a single row is what is returned. I didn't write the function or the manual, just trying to help you help yourself.

Comment: @Shackrock I understand you got confused by this function, the name is really confusing (at least for me). I think you should double check the rest of your code where you are using it ;)

Comment: @Sebas: MySQL has an optional parameter to return the entire resultset  or simply one row at a time. "The normal operation" of PHP has been decided like that to accomodate both operations. That way when you need multiple assocs, you simply put it an a while loop :]

Comment: It would mean creating a new function in php like `mysql_fetch_all_assoc` but people usually do: `while ($arr[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($result));` where `$arr` contains everything. But again it's using a loop because by design its how PHP is doing it to accomodate everyone's style.

Comment: haha, well i'll loop through it. but I SWEAR i have this same function returning an entire result set in other parts of the app, i'll try to find an example later in the week.

Comment: Eheh, if it's something you do often, why not :] But then you'd use your custom `mysql_fetch_all_assoc` to create an array... then do a foreach() on that array to play with the values... isn't it shorter to do everything in one step ? See xD ! In practice, most of the time when you fetch results you also want to iterate through them.

Comment: @AlexBelanger that's true.  In my case though, I fetch it all to a big array, then iterate through them (for display) using Smarty.

Comment: Yeah you're right, but I'm pretty sure mysql would LOVE having a bulk collect oracle style option...

Comment: Oh, Smarty needs an array to work.. makes sense! Have fun programming man!

Comment: @Sebas MySQL does return everything to PHP, but PHP only have the "fetch a row" mode to let you chose how you want to use the data yourself. It's really a design question more than capabilities, MySQL support both.

Comment: hmm you mean that if I have 10 billions rows recordset, it will be loaded to memory to php...??

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$questionsResult = mysql_query("select * from questions where userID = 1 AND active = 1"); // //Get all activated questions
if(mysql_num_rows($questionsResult) > 0){
    while($questions = mysql_fetch_assoc($questionsResult)){
      var_dump($questions);
    }
 }
```